# trying to get Mysql command line back to bash after entering mysql from command line within code?

Tags: mysql, bash, ubuntu

trying to get the code back into bash from mysql but having to manule type exit at

```
    else 
    echo "Continuting process"
    fi  **this is the end of the if else stament nested above**

    sudo apt-get install mysql-server
   mysql -u root -p;
    mysql> grant all privileges on KF4005"aaon@localhost";
    mysql> CREATE DATABASE F4005;
    mysql> use KF4005;
    mysql> CREATE TABLE filedata File name VARCHAR , File permissions VARCHAR, UserID INT, GroupID 
    INT,  Last accessed VARCHAR , Last Changed VARCHAR, Size INT, Last Modified VARCHAR , Birth 
    VARCHAR; 
    mysql> SHOW TABLES;
    mysql> LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Bashoutput.txt' INTO TABLE filedata;
    mysql> SELECT * FROM filedata;
    mysql> exit;
```

trying to return back to normal bash here but have to manule typepe exit

```
    exit;


        exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can press `CTRL` + `D` to exit MySQL.